listing comma correct usage

A change occurred, it affected the benefit, the claimant knew it, and they failed to declare the change.

Is 1) grammatically incorrect?
I think it is correct if you remove  'the claimant knew it' but how else would you put that in a list - perhaps (the claimant knew it) with brackets?
Resources use: I came, I saw, and I conquered, which repeats the subject I consistently but my example has two subjects within the list a change and they?

I'd start a new sentence after the first 3 words. Note that apart from the word "and",  I came, I saw, and I conquered is just translated from Latin - a language which I doubt even had the concepts of commas or sentences, so you shouldn't use that as a guide to English orthography.

@FumbleFingers - veni, vidi, vici, not an et in sight!. They made us say wayny weedy weeky.

This is straight editing: A change occurred that affected the benefit, the claimant knew it and he/she/ they failed to declare the change.

@MichaelHarvey: I suppose the "language boffins" have ways of knowing whether the ancient Romans were capable of enunciating our modern-day /w/ - where I'm more than happy to know that the "aspirated" version lampooned by Family Guy's Cool HWHip is going the way of all flesh. But I still cherish the thought that one day we'll find a clay pot from which we can extract / decode the conversation taking place near the potter's wheel that made it! :)

@FumbleFingers it's an interesting idea. Perhaps only the best pots are still resonating with the vibrations amongst which they were cast.

@FumbleFingers - For the Romans, 'v' was just another form of 'u'; it was only in later languages that it evolved into a consonant with its own sound.

@FumbleFingers - I gather that some clues come from renditions in other languages, e.g. Vesuvius was written in Greek as Ουεσούιοων ('Wesūwion'), and vae has come down to us as 'woe'.

@FumbleFingers my wife and I once undertook a long domestic task (chipping off all the tiles in the bathroom, goggles, hammers, & chisels) to the sound on repeat of the whole of Jeff Wayne's War of the Worlds, with narration by Richard Burton and we were greatly taken when he said that a Martian fighting machine, hit by an artillery shell, became '...now but a mere intricate device of metal whirling to destruction'. he says 'ha-wirling', and that is what we say still, twenty years on, if something gets drastically broken - it went ha-wirling to destruction


A change occurred, it affected the benefit, the claimant knew it, and they failed to declare the change.*

This is a series of statements. There’s nothing wrong here.
It’s a style question.
I could say: “I picked up the car, I drove to the shopping center, the store was open, I bought the cheese, and I got home by seven.”


A change occurred, it affected the benefit, the claimant knew it, and they failed to declare the change.

If you removed "the claimant knew it" as you suggest then it may not be clear who "they" refers to - unless that is clear from the wider context.
It sounds like you're talking about a benefit (what US English speakers would call 'welfare') claimant. Because the claimant (an individual) is a person of unspecified gender, the singular 'they' pronoun is correct. But unless this was very clear, one might think "they" referred to another party - perhaps the Department of Work and Pensions who administer the benefit? Whenever you use a pronoun, it must be clear who it refers to.
You asked how else it could be expressed differently (I presume with one less list item?).
Perhaps:

A change in the claimant's circumstances occurred, it affected their benefit, and they failed to declare the change.

This makes reference to the claimant from the outset, but indirectly by referring to their circumstances. This also makes it clear to someone less familiar with the process what 'changes' you are referring to - one might think it refers to a change in the eligibility criteria.


A change occurred, it affected the benefit, the claimant knew it, and they failed to declare the change.

There are no rules that limit the number of items in a series though the usual number is three.  Beyond three, readers may face difficulties following especially for series of lengthy items.
So I won't say your example is incorrect.
I agree with @Astralbee's approach to revise and combine some items and with @FumbleFingers' suggestion to start a new sentence:

A change occurred, it affected the benefit, [and] the claimant knew it.


They failed to declare the change.

The point in the second sentence stands alone and looks more powerful than it is as a fourth item in a longer series.
Series with four items have been used, and there's even a name Tetracolon for them.

Tetracolon climax (or simply tetracolon)
is a rhetorical term for a series of four members (words, phrases, or clauses), usually in parallel form.

I paste here a shorter and more recent example here:

Life is truly known only to those who suffer, lose, endure adversity and stumble from defeat to defeat."
(Ryszard Kapuscinski, "A Warsaw Diary." Granta, 1985)

A related question from ELU is here.
